# Failing to install elasticsearch-kopf plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I was trying to install kopf 2.1.2 to monitor Elasticsearch 7.7.0. in a Ubuntu 20.10 VM

First I downloaded the Zip file from github and placed it in the Downloads folder. Then I typed:

```
$ sudo ./elasticsearch-plugin install /home/user/Downloads/elasticsearch-kopf-2.1.2.zip
```

However I got the following output:

```
-> Installing /home/user/Downloads/elasticsearch-kopf-2.1.2.zip
-> Failed installing /home/user/Downloads/elasticsearch-kopf-2.1.2.zip
-> Rolling back /home/user/Downloads/elasticsearch-kopf-2.1.2.zip
-> Rolled back /home/user/Downloads/elasticsearch-kopf-2.1.2.zip
A tool for managing installed elasticsearch plugins
```

But no further information is provided.

Any idea what the issue might be?

Answer (score 0):

That plugin is no longer maintained and ES will not allow to install it after version 2.x because [site plugin support has been removed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/breaking_50_plugins.html#_site_plugins_removed) in ES 5.0.

As a result, that plugin author created a new plugin called [cerebro](https://github.com/lmenezes/cerebro) that you can use with any version of ES because it runs outside of ES and connects via the REST interface.

Go ahead and try it out.